# What is the image of the right half complex plane under the map $ f(z) = e^{2\pi i z} $

Tags: complex-analysis

My attemp

Let $H = \{z\in \mathbb{C} : Re(z)>0 \} $

$ f(z) = e^{2i\pi (x+iy) } = e^{-2\pi y} (\cos 2\pi x + i \sin 2 \pi x) $

$| \cos 2\pi x + i \sin 2 \pi x | = 1 \hspace{0.25cm} \forall x\in \mathbb{R} $ in addition if $y>0$ then $| e^{-2\pi y} | < 1 $ so $|f(z)| < 1 $. Thus $f$ maps $H$ into $D = \{ z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|<1 \}$ and for $z_0\in D$ implies $|z_0| =|z_0| |e^{2i\pi x}|$ because $|e^{2i\pi x}|=1 \hspace{0.25cm} \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $|z_0| = |e^{-2\pi y}| \ $ if $ \ y = -\frac{log |z_0| }{2\pi}$ with $ -log|z_0| > 0$. Therefore $ |z_0| = |e^{2i\pi (x+iy) }| $ i.e. $z_0 = f(x+iy) $ with $y>0$. Then $f$ maps $ \{z\in \mathbb{C} : Re(z)>0 , Im(z) > 0\} $ onto $D$

Is this right? and what happens with the case y<0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$. Let $w$ be any non-zero complex number. Let $\theta$ be its argument. Let $z=\frac {\log |w|+(\theta+2n\pi ) i} {2\pi i}$ where $n$ is a positive integer with $\theta +2n\pi  >0$. Then $e^{2\pi iz}=w$ and $\Re z=\frac {\theta+2n\pi} {2\pi} >0$.